# Can we use flutter for the existing Angular Application in the ways of micro frontend?

Tags: angular, flutter

We have an Angular 4  Application which needs to be migrated to flutter. As far the delivery concerned, Is there a possibility where we can parallelly run the existing application and new Flutter application as a micro frontend ?

We have an Angular 4  Application which needs to be migrated to flutter. As far the delivery concerned, Is there a possibility where we can parallelly run the existing application and new Flutter application as a micro frontend ?

Answer (score 0):

Putting the angular specifics aside - the Flutter issue for ["Render app inside custom html element"](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32329) may potentially be useful for you as there are other people in the same scenario, trying to migrate an angular application.

The issue was recently closed. With a solution making it possible to show one Flutter app inside a custom HTML element.

Comment: How to do the reverse? How to display an angular/vue app inside flutter app?

Comment: Not something I have done personally, but maybe try to use a WebView for this by providing the URL to where the application is hosted (or localhost while developing). Consider taking a look at these packages to see if they are useful to you: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview or https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter